# Groovy / jenkins : rename file

Tags: file, jenkins, groovy

I would like to rename lastModified() json as filename+"processing" in jenkins with groovy. I am unsuccessfully doing :

```
JSON_BASE_PATH="/json_repo/"

def file = new File(JSON_BASE_PATH).listFiles()?.sort { it.lastModified() }?.find{it=~/.json$/}
file.renameTo( new File( file.getName() + ".processing") )
print "Filename is : " + file
```

How to rename it ?

Comment: Update : renameTo is working fine. However file var is not reflecting the rename name. How to get new rename name ?

Answer (score 6):

You actually already have the answer in your code, you're just not storing it in a variable! `new File( file.getName() + ".processing")`

An instance of `File` isn't the *actual* entry on the file system, it's just a *representation* of one. So after you perform the rename, you need to work with the `File` instance that represents the *renamed* file system entry:

```
JSON_BASE_PATH="/json_repo/"

def file = new File(JSON_BASE_PATH).listFiles()?.sort { it.lastModified() }?.find{it=~/.json$/}
def modifiedFile = new File("${file.getName()}.processing")

/* Check their existence */
println "${file.getName()} exists? ${file.exists()}"
println "${modifiedFile.getName()} exists? ${modifiedFile.exists()}"

/* Rename the file system entry using the File objects */
file.renameTo(modifiedFile)

/* See what we have */
println "Original filename is: ${file}"
println "${file.getName()} exists? ${file.exists()}"
println "Modified Filename is: ${modifiedFile}"
println "${modifiedFile.getName()} exists? ${modifiedFile.exists()}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Update : renameTo is working fine. However file var is not reflecting the rename name. How to get new rename name ?